# HTML Element Tree jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin that will list all HTML elements of an HTML file in a tree, with all of the parent and child elements displayed within the tree. I've tested the highly suggested jstree jQuery plugin, but that plugin requires the nodes be inside an unordered list. Is there a workaround to use the jstree plugin so it lists all HTML elements or a plugin that doesn't required every HTML element to be inside an unordered list?

Comment: what difference does the element type make? Majority of all trees I have ever used were done using list elements

Comment: The tree needs to display a list of image, text, etc. elements from an HTML file displayed in a WYSIWYG on the same page. The elements in the HTML file aren't list elements and are not a child of a list element.

Comment: so why can't they be the content of `<li>`?

Comment: Hypothetically they could, but a PHP script would have to make them one and create a separate HTML file, so the format of the original file doesn't look like a giant list. I

Comment: Style has nothing to do with php...it is done with css

Comment: Yes, <li> is only CSS, but if I'm creating a script to add or replace the CSS to <li> for every HTML element, I would need to create a PHP script with conditionals that creates a separate HTML file, so the original HTML file and elements stay intact as they are.

Comment: Really depends on how the source is stored. If it is in database then structure can be anything. Not enough known about what you are working with

Answer (score 0):

Could you use Javascript? Easily done with that:

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

for(var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
  console.log(all[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Could you explain what this js script is doing? My javascript skills aren't the sharpest.

Comment: It's simple. We're using `getElementsByTagName` then passing in the `*` which stands for _all_ so it gets all elements in the DOM, then we simply loop through all those elements and do something with them. In my case I just `console.log`ged them but you could print them out to the screen or anything.